# How can I find out why a mono application is throwing a segmentation fault or an illegal instruction

Tags: c#, linux, multithreading, mono, arm

**Context**
We have an application running on mono on a ARM based device, once in a blue moon the application crashes with an illegal instruction or a segmentation fault (depending on the mono version used)

**What have I already done**
I have created a really simple application that shows the same behaviour, trying to rule out our own application

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (Program));
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Print();
            }
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Print();
            }
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Print()
    {
        Log.DebugFormat("msg from: {0}",Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var result = (AppSettingsSection)ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).GetSection("appSettings");
    }
}
```

This will throw

- an illegal instruction on mono version 4.0.3.13
- a segmentation fault on mono version: 4.2.1.60

Running in GDB gives the following information:

**mono 4.0.3.13**
  Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
[Switching to Thread 0x752ff430 (LWP 15107)]
0x0016a712 in verify_scan_starts (start=0x1dd19e "object", end=0x1 ) at sgen-gc.c:2116
2116                            SGEN_LOG (1, "NFC-BAD SCAN START [%zu] %p for obj [%p %p]", i, addr, start, end);

or

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
[Switching to Thread 0x754ff430 (LWP 4191)]
0x0016a712 in verify_scan_starts (start=0xffffffff ,
    end=0x1 ) at sgen-gc.c:2116
2116                            SGEN_LOG (1, "NFC-BAD SCAN START [%zu] %p for obj [%p %p]", i, addr, start, end);

**mono 4.2.1**
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x746ff430 (LWP 4493)]
0x00168008 in restart_handler (_dummy=, _info=, context=) at sgen-os-posix.c:167
167             errno = old_errno;
(gdb) bt 
`#0  0x00168008 in restart_handler (_dummy=, _info=, context=) at sgen-os-posix.c:167

## 1  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) mono_trace
Undefined command: "mono_trace".  Try "help".
(gdb) mono_backtrace
Missing argument 0 in user function.
(gdb) mono_stack

"Threadpool worker" tid=0x0x746ff430 this=0x0x75670300 thread handle 0x40d state : not waiting owns ()
  at  <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Type.internal_from_name (string,bool,bool) 
  at System.Type.GetType (string) [0x00011] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/4.2.1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/mcs                                 /class/corlib/ReferenceSources/Type.cs:49
  at System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationHost.GetConfigType (string,bool) [0x00000] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_6                                 4-linux/mono-native/4.2.1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/InternalConfigurationHost.cs:71
  at System.Configuration.ConfigInfo.CreateInstance () [0x00011] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/4.2.1                                 .60-r0/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ConfigInfo.cs:50
  at System.Configuration.SectionInfo.CreateInstance () [0x00000] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/4.2.                                 1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/SectionInfo.cs:63
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSectionInstance (System.Configuration.SectionInfo,bool) [0x00022] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/b                                 uild/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/4.2.1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:281
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionCollection.get_Item (string) [0x00032] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-lin                                 ux/mono-native/4.2.1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/ConfigurationSectionCollection.cs:68
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSection (string) [0x0001b] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/                                 4.2.1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:254
  at iltest.Program.Print () [0x00020] in e:\Libraries\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\iltest\Program.cs:60
  at iltest.Program.b__1 () [0x00004] in e:\Libraries\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\iltest\Program.cs:34
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<T_REF>.InnerInvoke () [0x00012] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/4.2                                 .1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:686
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/4.2.1.60-r0/mono                                 -4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2523
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback (object) [0x00007] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-                                 native/4.2.1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2887
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00                                 081] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/4.2.1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/t                                 hreading/executioncontext.cs:581
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in                                  /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/4.2.1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading                                 /executioncontext.cs:530
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal (System.Threading.Tasks.Task&) [0x0004c] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/wor                                 k/x86_64-linux/mono-native/4.2.1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2844
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry (bool) [0x0006f] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/4.2.1.6                                 0-r0/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2781
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00000] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/w                                 ork/x86_64-linux/mono-native/4.2.1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2728
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00096] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mono-native/4.2.1.                                 60-r0/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:859
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in /home/jdi/develop/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/mon                                 o-native/4.2.1.60-r0/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:1196
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00060, 0xffffffff>`

The question know is what can I do next to pinpoint the problem.

Thx for your expertise.

Regards, 
Bjorn

Comment: If it only ever crashes on Mono, and not on Windows, then you've probably found a bug(s) in Mono which you should report to them.